# Boost library not found | C++

Tags: c++, boost

I have a problem with Boost, as you can see on the screenshot of my term i can't compile because he say i don't have boost, but he's still here in /usr/lib/boost, please help me !

if you need more informations maybe i can give you, IDK ...

Thank in advance for your help

[image: my term]

[image: my makefil]

[image: an exemple of file.h who need boost]

[image: my boost path]

Comment: Why are the boost headers at `/usr/lib` instead of `/usr/include` you added this directory for linking but not for the headers.

Comment: @J'e as u can see in my screenshot of my Makefile i already use -l for my path include

Comment: Daaamn thanks @drescherjm it's works now

Answer (score 6):

Having the Boost header files in `/usr/lib/boost/` seems like a strange installation. Normally they would be in an "include" directory, like `/usr/include/boost/`.

If you need to keep the installation that way, the issue is that `/usr/lib` is not on your compiler's default include search path. So you'll need to specify it as a place to find included files. Add `-I /usr/lib` to the compile commands in your Makefile.

Comment: Yeah thanks i have move into /usr/include, thanks to auto install of boost who install herself in /usr/lib ...

Comment: @Sacha then you should accept this answer.